# how can we change the sass styling of div Y onclick of a button present in divX in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

how can I hide div with class name y using sass when I click on the button  present in div with class name x

const hide-divY=()=>{??}

```
<div className="x">
   <button onClick={hide-divY}/>
</div>
<div className="y">
</div>
```

Comment: you can make one state and toggle it and check that variable in y, if it true then you can add className else no className and className have `display: none` things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the task like below.

Your App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class MainDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hide: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const toggleDiv = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        hide: !this.state.hide
      });
    };

    return (
      <div className="main">
        <button type="button" onClick={toggleDiv}>
          Toggle Div
        </button>
        {this.state.hide ? ("") : (
          <div className="child-div">Child div is here</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainDiv;
```

In styles.scss (this can be anything)

```
.child-div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wescoff-p30yb?file=/src/styles.css:0-86